# HTML: Open a PDF file by Clicking on an Image

Tags: html, image, pdf

I am trying to make a Github pages website. I have an image of my report on my page. I want to be able to click on the image and have the PDF open up in a new tab. How would I do that?

Is this correct?

```
<a href="/uploads/ReportBlank.pdf"><img src="images/report_placeholder.png"/></a>
```

Comment: Yeap. Whether it opens in the user's browser or in some other software, though, is not under your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to *force* the browser to open in a new tab but giving the link a target may work in many browsers:

```
<a href="/uploads/ReportBlank.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/report_placeholder.png"/></a>
```

In practice, the users' software and preferences will mostly dictate where and what opens this file.

Comment: I don't think providing a `target` attribute has any bearing at all on whether the browser opens it or some other software does - as you say, that's down to prefs.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple add a image `<img>` inside a anchor tag `<a>`.

```
<a href="file.pdf">
     <img class="img-fluid" alt="open pdf" src="pdf-img.png">
</a>
```

If you want open PDF in new tab add `target="_blank"`